# Bellman Ford Algorithm relaxation

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

In the Bellman-Ford algorithm's relaxation part, I can't seem to understand why we need to use (d[v] = min{ d[v], d[u] + c(u, v) }), the (c(u,v)) part. This uses the original weight. Why can't it use the least cost(shortest) between (u,v) instead of c(u,v)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relaxation step we're trying to figure out if the shortest path to the source node from `v` needs to go through the edge `(u, v)`.

If the current shortest path we know - `d(v)` is longer than the shortest path from u `d(u)` plust the cost of the adge `c(u,v)` then we need to update `d(v)`'s value. Otherwise we keep `d(v)` as it was before.

We can't just do the minimum between `d[v]` and `d[u]` because for `v` to reach the source through `u` it needs to go through the edge  `(u,v)` which's cost needs to be incorporated into its final distance `d[v]`. So if you just update `d[v]` to be `d[u]` you're ignoring the cost of the edge between them.